# How does NPM start an Angular and Typescript application?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Would it be possible to get an explanation of how `npm start` works?

I have an Angular 2 application written in Typescript. I enter `npm start` in the console and this both compiles and launches the application using Node's built in web server.

However what is the starting point for this? Which files does the `npm start` command read in order to compile and start the application? Also why do I use `npm start` and not e.g. `node start`? I understood that NPM was just the package manager for node itself.

What I understand so far:

- I have a `tsconfig.js` file which tells the TypeScript compiler what to do.
- I have a `packages.json` file which tells node which packages to download.

Where do the following files fit into this:

`main.ts`

`app/app.module.ts` - which I understand is the starting point for my application.

How do all of these components fit together to form the application?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm start` is just an alias for `npm run start`, which runs whatever command is in `scripts.start` in your `package.json`.

It neither knows nor cares about TypeScript, or Angular, or anything like that - it just executes whatever script it's given on the command line.